# SQLite, how can I find a value that in my sentence？

Tags: sqlite

For example, a table like this:

> name  |  age  |  gender

> alice | 23 | female

> bob | 21 | male

> irfan | 24 | male

> ......

I get a sentence like "Hi, bob and alice!", I want to know the sentence if include the name in the table and return them. What should I do？

Like:

"Hi, bob and alice!" -> return the bob's value and alice value in the table

How to write SQL statements？

Comment: It's difficult to know what is a name and what is not. You would probably have to lookup every word alone. Of course you run into edge cases with common words that can also be a name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I may only be able to read each word to judge whether it is in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE 'Hi, bob and alice!' LIKE '%' || name || '%';
```

is a start.